# How to write raw html to browser from code behing in asp.net

Tags: asp.net, .net, visual-studio-2010, code-behind

I want to write a raw html page to the browser. I thought that something liek this would do it but this write to the current page:

```
Dim html as New StringBuilder
html.append("<html><body>A new html page</body></html>"
Response.Clear()
Response.Output.Write(html.ToString)
```

I know this can be done I just can't remember how

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to get the context object and then you can use something like this:

```
context.Response.Clear();

//Response.Charset = "UTF-8";
context.Response.ContentType = "text/html"

context.Response.AddHeader("Content-Length", length);

context.Response.OutputStream.Write((byte[])buffer, 0, filesize);
```

Comment: Right, I guess it depends where you call it from. I used it in a handler.